# SQL (mySQL) to find if there are cousins in some listed families

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to list all titles that have items in libraries A, B and D
There could also be items in library C, but I don't have to care about that

I have this SQL-query - is there a smarter way to do this? 
I guess the problem could be formulated as something like are there any cousins in those three listed familes?

(In real life I have to find items in 42 libraries, and the real question also involves reserves - so anything that makes the code shorter is appreciated)

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.biblionumber
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN biblio b ON (b.biblionumber=i.biblionumber)
WHERE i.homebranch = 'A'
AND EXISTS
(
    select *
    FROM items i2 
    WHERE i2.biblionumber = b.biblionumber
    AND i2.homebranch = 'B'
)
AND EXISTS
(
    select *
    FROM items i3 
    WHERE i3.biblionumber = b.biblionumber
    AND i3.homebranch = 'D'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your approach may performs the fastest, Yet you have to go for 42 searches, So You may try below query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.biblionumber
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN biblio b ON b.biblionumber=i.biblionumber
WHERE i.homebranch IN ('A', 'B', 'D', ...../* You Search List */)
GROUP BY i.homebranch
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT homebranch) = 42;
```